# Kubernetes redirect front-end to back-end

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, service, kubernetes-ingress

In Kubernetes I have a load balancer and 2 web apps (with names `UI` and `Kuard`) that are both publicly available through services and ingress rules similar to:

**Kuard Service:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |xxx
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-17T15:44:30Z"
  labels:
    app: kuard
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: pulumi
  name: mykuard
  namespace: nginx-test-frwjnfp0
  resourceVersion: "975"
  uid: 819d94ca-b63d-44d5-9af9-a83da3f4bbd8
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.3.250.8
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.3.250.8
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: kuard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**Kuard Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: | xxx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    pulumi.com/autonamed: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-17T15:44:42Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: kuard
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: pulumi
  name: kuard-tuy3sb0v
  namespace: nginx-test-frwjnfp0
  resourceVersion: "13091"
  uid: 4d14f3fc-d116-4233-a717-c38d92741139
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kuard.xxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: mykuard
            port:
              name: http
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xxx
```

As you can see for now I can access the Kuard app by going to `kuard.xxx.com` where xxx is the public LB IP.

Currently I am able to navigate to the `Kuard` app from the `UI` app by hardcoding `kuard.xxx.com` in my UI app. This is stupid because I'm using the WWW address rather than using the internal cluster address.

Which URL (and ingress?) can I use in order to open the `Kuard` app in the browser from the `UI` app based on its internal cluster address, rather than the WWW URL?

I tried hardcoding `http://mykuard:80` in the "UI" web app because the service name for the `Kuard` app is `mykuard`, but I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: You can only do that if the your "Kuard" app itself needs to access the UI. If the client (end user) needs to access the UI, they need to access it via the ingress, because that's the external entrypoint into the cluster. `http://mykuard:80` would be correct for inter-cluster communication.

Comment: how about including kuard as an iframe in ui?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think accessing the Kuard service through the ingress route is "stupid". Ingress is to expose the service to external clients like browsers (and iframes), whereas internal cluster addresses are for other pods to each Kuard directly. If your "UI" app is running on Nginx or something, then you could proxy traffic through it, e.g. `ui.xxx.com/kuard -> http://mykuard:80`

Comment: okay, thx for the explanation. Any tips on how to setup such a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible.

When accessing a service from a browser, you are making request from outside your cluster. For this you need external IP.

The internal cluster address (`<service-name>:<port>`) is for internal communication only (e.g. pod to pod) , and is resolved by your internal DNS, to which your browser does not have access.